# Rails API and Firebase deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, firebase, rails-api

I have implemented an web application, Now I want to deploy it on firebase. I have used `React` for the `frontend` and `Rails` for the `backend`. So I had use `rack cors` gem in rails. Also I have used `postgresql` in rails app api. So how I will deploy the rails api to the firebase. I did lot of google but did not able to find proper solution. 
I have Implemented Rails Api.

Comment: Rails is a backend framework. As such, I'm not sure it can be deployed to Firebase. Check out Heroku instead.